# cabal build --ghc-option=-ddump-minimal-imports does not produce import files for main

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

ddump-minimal-imports is a valuable tool. i cannot make it work for the executable and test-suites in my cabal file.

in my cabal file i have:

```
test-suite testDatas6forTestDataItem
    type:       exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:    Datas6TestDataItemTest.hs
    build-depends:
       base -any,
       time,
       monads-tf, 

    default-language: Haskell2010
    hs-source-dirs: ., srcexe
    ghc-options: -threaded  -ddump-minimal-imports
```

i find the imports files for the modules in the dist folder, but nothing for the tests and mains. 
is this

- due to some error on my part?
- intentional behaviour?
- the result of some technical limitations?

thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected they were emitted, just not where you might expect, so I ran an experiment and confirmed this. I forked kazu's [test example package](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/unit-test-example) then added the extra minimal import flags to the cabal file like so:

```
Test-Suite doctest
  Type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  ...
  ghc-options: -threaded  -ddump-minimal-imports

Test-Suite spec
  Type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  ...
  ghc-options: -threaded  -ddump-minimal-imports
```

And the files *did* show up under `dist` in `dist/build/doctest/doctest-tmp/Main.imports` and `dist/build/spec/spec-tmp/Main.imports`. For the `spec`, which had other files in the suite as well, their imports also showed up in the same directory.